# How do you switch visual studio code syntax highlighting to typescript 2.0 beta?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've done 
`npm install -g typescript@beta`
`npm install -i --save-dev typescript@beta`

installed the insiders typescript visual studio code.

After such i insert the following line into my project from their typescript 2.0 announcement and vscode highlights it as not valid.

`let foo: string | null = null;`

If it is important my project was created with `ng new my-project`.

Also here is my project.json file and tslint.json file

```
{
  "name": "portal-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.8",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.20",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rx-socket-subject": "^0.7.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.9",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "3.11.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "typings": "0.8.1"
  }
}
```

tslint.json

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "label-position": true,
    "label-undefined": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      "static-before-instance",
      "variables-before-functions"
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-key": true,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": true,
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-unused-variable": true,
    "no-unreachable": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],

    "directive-selector-name": [true, "camelCase"],
    "component-selector-name": [true, "kebab-case"],
    "directive-selector-type": [true, "attribute"],
    "component-selector-type": [true, "element"],
    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true
  }
}
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/07/11/announcing-typescript-2-0-beta/

Comment: are you suggesting i ask there or are you suggesting the answer is there. If the later, i've already followed that guide

Comment: I would assume the answer is there.

Comment: Not that i can find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a place that has directions (link below).

**Summary:** 
ctrl+shift+p -> type user settings

add the following line changing the path to where tsc 2.0 lives on your machine.

`"typescript.tsdk": "c:\\users\\mmeisberger\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib"`

Restart your IDE.

**Official instructions here:** 
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions

Comment: If you are using angular-cli and you want typescript 2.0 you'll need to get the compiler to use it. Currently the only way I can figure out how to do that is cp node_modules/typescript into node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules

Comment: This has no impact on the syntax highlighting 

Comment: have you restarted the ide after you made the change? Are you certain you have the right path, that the folder exists. Also if you open up terminal and navigate to the typescript folder and do something like ./tsc --version and make sure that it is 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

> visual studio code syntax highlighting to typescript 2.0 beta

VSCode does not use `typescript` to provide its syntax highlighting. It actually uses `textmate` which has a *few* bugs : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-TmLanguage/issues

## More

alm supports ts 2 out of the box `npm install alm -g` And actually uses the TypeScript compiler to provide the highlighting ... [Not Text Mate](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/alm/content/features/typescript.html#syntax-highlighting)

Comment: Interesting. I'll definitely have to give alm a try

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mac, you may install **typescript 2.0** by `npm install typescript@2.0 -g` for global usage. Then, type `npm list typescript -g` to show the path:

```
$ npm list typescript -g
/usr/local/lib
└── typescript@2.0.3
```

And you'll find the command `tsc` and `tsserver` should be in the path `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib`.

Now, open the preferences of **Virtual Studio Code** (`cmd + ,`), and add the following to the `settings.json`

```
{
  ...,
  "typescript.tsdk": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

Restart **Virtual Studio Code**, and open a TypeScript file, now it should highlight TS code as `2.x`.